# i wanted to know what exactly happens in the following java code for printing a triangle :

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

code 1 : I have declared `int b = 0` outside the first while loop:

```
public class apples {
public static void main(String args[]){

    int a = 1;

    int b = 0;  

    while (a < 5){



            while(b < a){
            System.out.print("y");
            b++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        a++;
    }

}
```

}

Result :

```
y
y
y
y
```

Code 2 : Here I declared `int b = 0` inside of the first while loop:

```
public class apples {
public static void main(String args[]){

    int a = 1;

    while (a < 5){

        int b = 0;
            while(b < a){
            System.out.print("y");
            b++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        a++;
    }

}
```

}

Result :

```
y
yy
yyy
yyyy
```

As you can see, I have different results, when I declare `int b = 0` inside the first while'loop and outside that loop.
Can anyone explain why that happens ?
Thanks already!

Comment: is this technically a code review question?

Comment: if you're ever wondering why output is the way it is, a top tip is to run your debugger and actually step through the code looking at the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, enough `System.out.println`s is never enough, you can learn a lot by simply writing:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 0;

while (a < 5) {
    System.out.println("Outer loop: a="+a+", b="+b);
    while (b < a) {
        System.out.println("Inner loop: a="+a+", b="+b);
        b++;
    }

    System.out.println();
    a++;
}
```

Play with it, change the initial values, reset values after/before inner loop, ... It's the best way to learn something.

Comment: I keep seeing the accepted response changing. This is the best response because you can use it for all your future problems. Mine is just explaining what happens in your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm new to this.  I was trying to accept all the below answers too, but i realised i can select only one.
But thanks a lot everyone for clearing it for me ! :)

Answer (score 1):

When b is outside the loop there will be always one print because both `a` and `b` are initialized only once so it works like so:

```
b=0 a=1 -> 1 iteration for b to be equal to a -> 1 print

b=1 a=2 -> 1 iteration for b to be equal to a -> 1 print and so on
```

In the second loop `a` increases the same way but `b` is always initialized with 0 in the loop so it would work like this:

```
b=0 a=1 -> 1 iteration for b to be equal to a -> one print 

b=0 a=2 -> 2 iterations for b to be equal to a -> two prints and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, b is initially 0, and a is 1, goes into loop, prints one y, then b becomes 1, *Now b is no longer greater than1.* So it goes onto incrementing a and looping. Now b=1, a=2, again it goes to inner loop, *prints y again only once* because 1 now becomes 2, and 2( of b) is not greater than 2(of a) So on, you get only 1 y per line

In second case, *b is reinitialized to zero every time outer loop iterates*. So each time it prints more 'y's.

See below values of a,b for which a 'y' is printed

Case 1:

```
0,1
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
```

Case 2:

```
0,1
0,2
1,2
0,3
1,3
2,3
0,4
1,4
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, you have difficulties in diagnosing and [tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_%28software%29) the code which is somewhat a crucial aspect in programming. Since your example is easy to trace manually(which you should try first, as kajackx's answer) for more complex pieces of code, you should learn how to use debugging tools. Assuming you are using eclipse, check this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility?)